# Show scrollbar in QTreeWidget with respect to the custom item widgets' size

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 for my application and a QTreeWidget to display content. Since I need to display rich text (HTML) each item has its text property set to "" and I create individual QLabels with the desired text. I then use `QTreeWidget.setItemWidget`. My problem is that using that method, when the QTreeWidget is smaller (in width) than the items' width, the horizontal scrollbar is not displayed. Which is logical, since from the point of view of the QTreeWidget, each item has width 0 because its text is empty.

I tried using a custom helper method that I use instead of the `QLabel.setText` method by automatically calling `QLabel.setFixedSize` method afterwards, but it doesn't work very well (the size is off by 5 to 90 pixels each time).

How would it be possible to make the whole thing determine automatically when to show the scrollbar, and what width to use for them?

**MCVE**:

```
tree = QTreeWidget()
item = QTreeWidgetItem(tree)
label = QLabel()
label.setText("<b>some text here</b>")
tree.setItemWidget(item, 0, label)
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: An MCVE is not a list of requirements! You are being asked to show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I even struggled with the same problem and finally this solution works for me:

- Set the treewidget header *StretchLastSection* to False
- `treeWidget.header()->setSectionResizeMode(column, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)`

Comment: This trick works, but only for the root item (i.e. it resizes everything according to the size of the root item). So basically it only works correctly if there is only one item in the TreeWidget

Comment: Actually, adding `item.setSizeHint(0, label.sizeHint())` **and** StretchLastSection to False solved the problem!